# Replace a numerical value by NA based on conditions from other columns:

Tags: r, data.table

I am new to data.table package, please execuse my simple question. I have a data set that looks like DT

```
DT <- data.table(a = sample(c("C","M","Y","K"),  100, rep=TRUE),
                   b = sample(c("A","S"),  100, rep=TRUE),
                   f = round(rnorm(n=100, mean=.90, sd=.08),digits = 2) ); DT
```

I would like to replace any value in column f with NA if it meets a certain condition. For example for `0.85 > f > 0.90` I would have the following condition:

```
DT$a == "C" & DT$b == "S" & DT$f < .85| DT$a == "C" & DT$b == "S" & DT$f >.90
```

I would also like to have a different condition for each of the categorical variables in columns a and b.

Comment: Wow, the post changed a lot!

Comment: Hi Ragy. Arun answered your initial question, so typical Stack Overflow protocol would be to accept his answer and (if you need to) ask a new one rather than edit the initial one. Long experience shows that a one topic per question works best, both for potential answerers and for future readers of the exchange!

Comment: Thanks Josh, sounds logical. If I ask a new question, how can I refer to my old question?

Comment: I rolled this question back to it's original state. Please refrain from editing your question into something completely different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the condition you've stated, but without the `DT$` will subset your `data.table` for those entries that satisfy the condition, then you can use the `j` field to assign NA value to `f` by reference using `:=` operator. That is,

```
DT[a == "C" & b == "S" & f < .85 | a == "C" & b == "S" & f >.90, f := NA]
which(is.na(DT$f))
# [1]  3 16 31 89
```

**Edit:** after OP's comment and @Joshua's nice suggestion:

```
`%between%` <- function(x, vals) { x >= vals[1] & x <= vals[2]}
`%nbetween%` <- Negate(`%between%`)
DT[a %in% c("C", "M", "Y", "K") & b == "S" & f %nbetween% c(0.85, 0.90), f := NA]
```

`%nbetween%` which is the negation of the `%between%` will give the desired result (f < 0.85 and f > 0.90). Also note the use of `%in%` to check for multiple values of `a`

**Edit 2:** Following OP's complete re-write, I'm afraid there's not much you can do, except group b == "A", b == "S".

```
`%nbetween%` <- Negate(`%between%`)
DT[a == "M" & b %in% c("A", "S") & f %nbetween% c(.85, .90), f := NA]
DT[a == "Y" & b %in% c("A", "S") & f %nbetween% c(.95, .90), f := NA]
DT[a == "K" & b %in% c("A", "S") & f %nbetween% c(.95, 1.10), f := NA]
```

Comment: Thanks Arun, I also would like to cycle through all the categorical variables in columns a and b

Comment: This might be a bit easier to read: `DT[a == "C" & b == "S" & ! f %between% c(.85, .90), f := NA]`.

Comment: for example i would like to do the following all in one step DT[a == "M" & b == "S" & ! f %between% c(.85, .90), f := NA] and DT[a == "Y" & b == "S" & ! f %between% c(.85, .90), f := NA] and DT[a == "K" & b == "S" & ! f %between% c(.85, .90), f := NA] and then repeat the above for "A"