# Replace a numerical value by NA based on conditions from other columns

Tags: r, data.table

This is related to a prior question which can be found in:

[Replace a numerical value by NA based on conditions from other columns:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15768417/)

Below is the data:

```
DT <- data.table(a = sample(c("C","M","Y","K"),  100, rep=TRUE),
                   b = sample(c("A","S"),  100, rep=TRUE),
                   f = round(rnorm(n=100, mean=.90, sd=.08),digits = 2) ); DT
```

I would like an elegant and succinct re-write for the following functions:

```
`%between%` <- function(x, vals) { x >= vals[1] & x <= vals[2]}
`%nbetween%` <- Negate(`%between%`)
```

and the following script to replace a certain values that meet certain conditions with NA

```
DT[a == "C" & b %in% c("A", "S") & f %nbetween% c(.85, .95), f := NA]
DT[a == "M" & b %in% c("A", "S") & f %nbetween% c(.85, .95), f := NA]
DT[a == "Y" & b %in% c("A", "S") & f %nbetween% c(.80, .90), f := NA]
DT[a == "K" & b %in% c("A", "S") & f %nbetween% c(.95, 1.10), f := NA]
```

Comment: Those seem both elegant and succinct to me.  Maybe you can expand on your question to include how this isn't good enoguh?  You can use `keys` on your `data.table` and the `J()` function to do your subsetting to avoid vector searches.

Comment: I following on what schools taught me, don't retype; write a function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you vectorize your function, then you can make it a little more elegant:

```
`%between%` <- function(x, vals, vals2)  x >= vals & x <= vals2
`%nbetween%` <- Negate(`%between%`)

# This will get you a nice ranges table.
ranges<-data.table(a=c('C','M','Y','K'),low=c(0.85,0.85,0.80,0.95),high=c(0.95,0.95,0.90,1.10))
# Set the keys for an easy merge.
setkeyv(ranges,'a')
setkeyv(DT,'a')
# Merge and filter.    
DT<-merge(DT,ranges,all.x=TRUE)[b %in% c('A','S') & `%nbetween%`(f,low,high),f:=NA ]
# A nice suggestion from the comments:
DT<-DT[ranges][b %in% c('A','S') & `%nbetween%`(f,low,high),f:=NA]

#     a b    f  low high
#  1: C S 0.88 0.85 0.95
#  2: C S   NA 0.85 0.95
#  3: C S 0.92 0.85 0.95
#  4: C A 0.94 0.85 0.95
#  5: C S   NA 0.85 0.95
#  6: C S 0.90 0.85 0.95
```

Comment: Perhaps last line should be (to change by reference, not by copy): ``DT[ranges][b %in% c('A','S') & `%nbetween%`(f,low,high),f:=NA]``

Comment: Thank you so much nograpes, I like it