# R data.table package - adding values in columns using := operator

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

**Question**

I have a data.frame, and want to place data in a column, based on the data from others columns.

So here's an example of my data.frame (shortened version):

```
Fertilization=c("N0","N0","N0","N0","N2","N2","N2","N2")
Sowing=c("S1","S1","S2","S2","S1","S1","S2","S2")
FoliarRank=c("F2","F3","F2","F3","F2","F3","F2","F3")
New_FoliarRank=rep(0,length(Fertilization))
DT=data.frame(Fertilization,Sowing,FoliarRank,New_FoliarRank)
```

I want to give values to New_FoliarRank based on conditions in the columns Fertilization, Sowing, FoliarRank.
For instance:

- if Fertilization=="N0", Sowing=="S1" and FoliarRank=="F2", then New_FoliarRank=="F3*"
- if Fertilization=="N0", Sowing=="S1" and FoliarRank=="F3", then New_FoliarRank=="F2*"

As for solutions:

- I can make it work with a bunch for/if, but it will be slow and not
  very "R-ish", perhaps even if I "apply" it
- as I understood, I can use the := operator for the
  {data.table} package. It could be much  better. Actually, it has been
  discussed elsewhere on Stack Overflow ["Replace a numerical value by
  NA based on conditions from other columns"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15770317/replace-a-numerical-value-by-na-based-on-conditions-from-other-columns?lq=1) But I can't find a way to make this post's solution work. And I don't understand why, even when looking at ?":=". I'm missing something, perhaps obvious, so I thought I could ask. Sorry for the duplicate.

Some of the solutions I tried:

```
library(data.table)
DT[Fertilization=="N0" & Sowing=="S1" & FoliarRank=="F2", New_FoliarRank:="F3*"] # seems to be same script as other post
DT[ , New_FoliarRank:= {Fertilization=="N0" & Sowing=="S1" & FoliarRank=="F2"; "F3*"}] # adapted from another post; doesn't work either
```

And it gives me in return:

```
Error in `:=`(New_FoliarRank, "F3*") : 
Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").
```

**Solutions proposed (another solution is posted below)**

```
# Initial vectors (no need for New_FoliarRank)
Fertilization=c("N0","N0","N0","N0","N2","N2","N2","N2")
Sowing=c("S1","S1","S2","S2","S1","S1","S2","S2")
FoliarRank=c("F2","F3","F2","F3","F2","F3","F2","F3")

# Actually I was missing the class of DT (data.table instead of data.frame)
DT=data.table(Fertilization,Sowing,FoliarRank)

library(data.table)
# And I shouldn't have created New_FoliarRank (esp. in with numerical values), as it is created "on the spot"
setDT(DT)[Fertilization=="N0" & Sowing=="S1" & FoliarRank=="F2", New_FoliarRank := "F3*"]
setDT(DT)[Fertilization=="N0" & Sowing=="S1" & FoliarRank=="F3", New_FoliarRank := "F2*"]
```

Comment: @ akrun: No there is more than two conditions (28 actually in the complete data.frame, that I can't publish online). At the end of the script, there will be no zeros anymore in New_FoliarRank (new values instead: F1*, F2*, F3*, etc.).

Comment: Don't create `New_FoliarRank` before running the code because you made it numeric column and trying to add character values. Also don't forget to convert `DT` to a data.table object. If you won't creat that column, you can just run several lines as follows (with different conditions each time) `setDT(DT)[Fertilization=="N0" & Sowing=="S1" & FoliarRank=="F2", New_FoliarRank := "w"]` and everything will work fine

Comment: @DavidArenburg Well, they should initialize the column. Just to the correct class.

Comment: @Roland They don't have to. But they can. I think it mainly depends on own preference. I never do that, for example.

Comment: @ everyone: thanks for your time. I changed the class of DT using as.data.table() and initialized New_FoliarRank with "a" insted of zeros i.e. New_FoliarRank=rep("a", length(Fertilization)). It does the trick!

Comment: Two questions now: how to pass the post into "solved", and to add the Answer?

Comment: You don't need to initialize the column. Other than that you can post the answer you come up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use factors:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DT)
DT[, New_FoliarRank := interaction(Fertilization, Sowing, FoliarRank)]
#check levels
levels(DT[, New_FoliarRank])

#assign new labels
DT[, New_FoliarRank := factor(New_FoliarRank, 
                              levels = levels(New_FoliarRank),
                              labels = c("012", "212", "022", "222", "013", "213", "023", "223"))]

#   Fertilization Sowing FoliarRank New_FoliarRank
#1:            N0     S1         F2            012
#2:            N0     S1         F3            013
#3:            N0     S2         F2            022
#4:            N0     S2         F3            023
#5:            N2     S1         F2            212
#6:            N2     S1         F3            213
#7:            N2     S2         F2            222
#8:            N2     S2         F3            223
```

Comment: @ Roland: thanks, that's a great answer too. I'll publish the solutions proposed above in my original post, and mark your post as answer to Solve the topic.